# Undefined variable: whitelist whenever trying to interact with files

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

For some reason im getting these errors whenever i interact with the file manager

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: whitelist
Filename: libraries/Mime_type.php
Line Number: 48

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: 4096
Message: Argument 1 passed to EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Library\Mime\MimeType::addMimeTypes() must be of the type array, null given, called in /home/forge/default/system/expressionengine/libraries/Mime_type.php on line 48 and defined
Filename: Mime/MimeType.php
Line Number: 82

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Filename: Mime/MimeType.php
Line Number: 84
```

It wont let me upload new files, or synchronize directories?

Its running EE 2.10.1, on a laravel forge made server.  I checked all the folder permissions and it looks fine? any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run an EE upgrade recently?? They changed how they detect mime types:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html

Look at the change log for 2.10. They use a different mime-type library now... sounds like you upgraded, but it's possible your PHP version is out of date or missing a required module... please let us know your EE version, if you've upgraded, and your PHP and Apache version.

**Edit** Ahhhh... check out this file:

```
system/expressionengine/config/mimes.php
```

Does it look like this, and does it have file permissions set to 664??

```
$whitelist = array(
    'application/csv', // .csv
    'application/epub+zip', // .epub
    'application/excel', // .csv, .xl, .

    /* and so on ... */

    'video/x-ms-wmv', // .wmv
    'video/x-msvideo', // .avi
    'video/x-sgi-movie', // .movie
);
```

It's possible, that for some reason, that file wasn't updated. They changed the variable name of how they stored mime types as well.

Comment: I did upgrade recently and its running nginx instead of apache, maybe thats related?

Comment: As for php its 5.6.7 so that should be ok?

Comment: @KeithMancuso Answer updated.

Comment: Ahh yes! that was it, looks like that file wasnt updated.  I normally skip the config folder when doing updates but i guess thats where i went wrong.  Thanks so much!